# PHP API session vs token for authentication

Tags: php, api, session

I am trying to make a private API for internal use for my website and own mobile app and I am trying to add authentication but everywhere I look it says to use tokens and not sessions

But is it  not the same thing in actuality and just a text string with a different name?

If I POST to login.php?PHPSESSID=XXX or /api/loginuser?token=XXX they are sent with every request, authenticated on server side/database and identify the user that is logged in

??? Its seems like token and session id are exactly the same just the token you have to generate yourself and session has built in functions or am I totally missing something? I understand PHP sessions are only in PHP, so is that why the confusion? because other programming languages don't have their own session so they created a token?

Comment: you shouldn't use sessions for API use because sessions contain data, but that data is stored on the server and the only way to access it is to have the cookie with the correct php session id so that php knows what to do. When you hit a webpage using any form other than the user navigating to such page, the cookie needs to be recreated. It's loads easier to generate tokens that you can use to access a user's resource pool on your own without the "help" of php. using the token method, you can save every session and retrieve as necessary, but with sessions you don't have that level of control.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I meant session id..are session id's and tokens/cookies,etc not the same thing? just a text string that identifies the client (and data stored on the server)

Answer (score 3):

Tokens are usually used in RESTful APIs. The reason that one application uses token is to keep it's API *stateless* – one of the principles of designing RESTful APIs. Tokens are not stored on the server and this is the factor that makes them different from sessions and cookies.

> ... because other programming languages don't have their own session so they created a token?

No, as it has been mentioned the main point of using tokens is to keep the API stateless. Even APIs that have been written in PHP may use tokens. For example, the [JSON Web Tokens (JWT)](http://jwt.io/) that now is considered an [industry standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519) has a PHP library.